# matched pair vs dual BJTs

Tags: analog, bjt

Is there any practical difference between a matched pair of transistors and dual transistors in one package? Realistically, the latter are also two transistors from the same die, so they should be quite identical.

For example, the Diodes Inc. [DMMT3906W](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30312.pdf) is advertised as a matched PNP pair, while the Nexperia [PMBT3906YS](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMBT3906YS.pdf) is "only" a dual PNP. Regarding the other parameters they are very similar components.

So is there a real difference or is it that Diodes just does more meticulous tests and is therefore more confident in their specs?

For context, in my application i am looking for a close tracking of base-emitter voltage over temperature.

Comment: Probably testing is the difference. If you make wafers full of devices, you test them and then bin them (where appropriate.) This is probably the case here. They use pogo pins and run around the wafer testing each die. Those that meet the specifications for a matched pair (say, beta only or else beta and saturation current) are marked as such. When they are cut, they get binned. Compare BCV61 with BCM61, for example.

Comment: I don't know what is driving you to need a discrete couple of BJTs, and for sure you're going to have lots of circuital reasons, but I'm quite sure that choosing a topology which doesn't need any is the best option by far.

Comment: @carloc You're absolutely right about avoiding those things. I had spent two decades in electronics before I got into a situation where I need coupled BJTs, but here I am.

Comment: I see, If possible I'd use plenty of degeneration, i.e. emitter resistors or negative feedback, to reduce sensitivity from BJTs parameters

Comment: @carloc  4ish years on: I'm designing equipment which is crucially cost sensitive. I need two high side current sense circuits. Matched PNP pairs allow formation of a current mirror to form a circuit that amplifies a high side voltage drop and output the result  relative to ground. Uses two transistors in a single pkg to replace a $1 + to ++ IC.

Answer (score 2):

several issues here:

the thermal timeconstant depends upon the distance between the emitters of the two transistors

The smallest distance for bipolars casually thrown onto silicon, perhaps in a 5-transistor array like CA3046, is 20 to 50 microns. Harris Semi produced(s) a high-speed variant, which of course will have a new layout.

Given the thermal timeconstant of 1 cubic meter of silicon is 11,400 seconds, and the thermal timeconstant of 10 microns is (1 meter/10micron)^2 faster or 10^10 faster, or 1.14 microseconds, you should not expect ultra-high-speed pulse processing to benefit from thermally-tracking bipolars.

Perhaps ComLinear opamps (long ago acquired by some other semi company) realized this, and laid out their input diffpair devices in very tight physical patterns, so the 2 emitters were very close.

And now the second thought: you can cascode the devices, to reduce the Vce and thus reduce the self-heating. You might also adjust each Vce slightly as Ic varies, and thus keep the Ic * Vce constant in each of the two diffpair devices.

For this last --- keeping the Ic * Vce constant --- go review the translinear principle of Barry Gilbert.

[had an error: should have been cascode; I first wrote cascade]

Answer (score 2):

Since thermal tracking is important, what you should look for are monolithic pairs. The " matched " pairs in a SOT23 are two separate dice in one package, and will not track well. There used to be mfgs that specialized in these and some linear IC companies sell them as well. I still have a AD820 I got from Analog Devices in the 1970s, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's relevant here, but matched transistors should be at the same temperature (Vbe varies with temperature at 2mV/°C).

Yet it turns out that in a lot of applications (current mirrors...), one transistor dissipates more power than the other.

So the matching depends (among other thing) from the thermal coupling between the two transistors.

If the transistors are adjacent on the same die, I presume that they are not separated in the mounting process, so it's a way better for the coupling.

Unortunately, I have absolutely no informations about the geometry inside the packaging, so I can't quantify all this.

Needless to say that simulator (spice...) can't simulate this without a lot of contrieved efforts.

Comment: I did not consider thermal coupling being an issue here. Are you suggesting that it might be feasible to have two dies in a SOT-363 package?

Comment: Two dies in a same SOT-363 ? I don't know if this can happen. I think it is rather unlikely because it's probably more expensive to produce. But, it is what I understood at first sight from the comment of @jonk. Maybe I missunberstood. Anyway, I had the experience of two mismatched diodes in the same package (SOT23) because of thermal heating of one diode (I was working in the range of a few millivolt) and I was wondering if this was possible if the die is common.

Comment: From your description it is entirely possible that your two diodes in the SOT-23 had the same temperature, but were mismatched regarding component characteristics, e.g. saturation current.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that the mismatch came from a temperature difference between the diodes because the mismatch was changing when I warmed only one pin of the SOT23 (one pin that is not in common to both diodes). It was a long time ago (between 1995 and 2000). And so far I remember, there was no mismatch without such temperature gradient.

Comment: ...  and without auto-heating of the component.

Comment: @andre314 I think you misunderstood me. Both bjts are designed to be on the same die and are quite thermally coupled. It is just that not all such pairs are as matched as one might like. Testing then determines which pairs are better matched than others.

Comment: @jonk Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @andre314 No problem. A wafer will have some dice that are completely out of spec or simply don't work at all. Those will also be marked for destruction (thrown away) before ever being packaged (expensive.) But those which are very well matched and work fine will be pulled out and sold for more money. The testing has to be done, anyway, before wasting money on packaging. They may as well make the most money they can get. So the bcv61/62 pairs and the bcm61/62 pairs, I think, all come from the same wafer processes. Just get labeled differently, depending on testing results.

Comment: @andre314 I have and use those pairs, by the way. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't specified, you can't rely on it.

The DMMT3906W is "intrinsically matched" because the transistors are adjacent from the same die, but there is no other specification about how much they are matched.  So nothing indicates that they are triaged with regards to their "matching" parameters. 
 The applications targeted by this component include "Current Mirrors".

The PMBT3906YS does not say anything about matching whatsoever, and the applications targeted are "General-purpose switching and amplification".

Diodes Inc. does not do more meticulous tests for this product as far as I can see - they "only" know that these transistors are one next to the other from the same die.
If the transistors do not match after all, there is nothing in the specification that will allow you to complain about it.

Comment: I see some issues with your answer:
1. "If the transistors do not match after all, there is nothing in the specification that will allow you to complain about it.": There is a clear spec on matching in the Diodes datasheet. So I have every right to complain and have my colleagues from quality kick their butt.
2. "these transistors are one next to the other from the same die": That should be true for the Nexperia as well. Having two dies in a SOT-363 does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, they are next to each other on the die and if they are not you can complain about that, but there is no other guarantee.  Being neighbours does not mean that they are matching - it is only very likely that they are.  One of the transistors could be subject to a local impurity and not the other one.  In that case the transistors would not match as perfectly as other ones and they can both still be within specs.
I agree that the Nexperia diodes are likely the same die/chip but they did not specify their component as useable for current mirrors, etc - only as "general purpose  transistors".

Comment: "2. That should be true for the Nexperia as well." - Probably, but it isn't in their specification so you can't rely on it.